# ¿Cómo hacer para que se muestre el mensaje:Este producto ya existe en la tabla productos, cuando se quiera insertar un nombre o código que ya existe?

Tags: sql-server

Cree un procedimiento en sql que inserta el nombre y código de un producto pero quiero que se muestre el mensaje: "Este producto ya existe en la tabla productos", cuando el nombre del producto o el código ya existan.

```
alter proc insertProducts
@nombre varchar(50),
@codigo_producto varchar(50)
as
insert into productos(nombre,codigo_producto) values(@nombre,@codigo_producto)
go
```

Comment: Hay varias formas, una de ellas podría ser crear otro procedimiento almacenado que verifique eso y que retorne un BIT (true/false), a nivel de capa de aplicación retornar el valor de la verificación y en la capa de diseño/presentación/UI mostrar ese valor :D

Answer (score 1):

Si no debes de tener productos con nombres o códigos repetidos, lo mejor es que pongas la validación desde la definición de la tabla con un par de constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE productos ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_productos_nombre UNIQUE ( nombre);

ALTER TABLE productos ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_productos_codigo_producto UNIQUE ( codigo_producto);
```

Una vez que tengas esa validación, solo tienes que capturar el error.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE insertProducts(
    @nombre varchar(50) = 'Producto de Prueba',
    @codigo_producto varchar(50) = 'Prueba'
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO productos(
            nombre,
            codigo_producto
    ) 
    VALUES(
            @nombre,
            @codigo_producto
    );
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF  ERROR_NUMBER() = 2627
        THROW 50001, 'Este producto ya existe en la tabla productos', 1;
    ELSE
        THROW;
END CATCH;
GO
```

Esta opción evita tener que leer varias veces la tabla para verificar la existencia, maneja adecuadamente la concurrencia para evitar duplicados y evita que haya duplicados aunque no se use directamente el procedimiento.